# openGL glBufferData usage

Tags: qt, opengl, buffer

I am using glBufferData to save some information for rendering.

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_size * sizeof(VertexData), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

where vertices save data for each vertexs. I changed vertices data later to render a different image. However, it is still showing the original one. I believe changing GL_STATIC_DRAW to GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW should solve the problem, but it failed. What should I do for that?

Comment: Calling `glBufferData()` again with new data should work fine.  Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update your entire buffer, you should call `glBufferData()` once again:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_size * sizeof(VertexData), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Furthermore, it is possible to update only part of the data using the `glBufferSubData()` call:

```
glBufferSubData(GLenum target, GLintptr offset, GLsizeiptr size, const GLvoid* data);
```

The `glBufferSubData()` is faster since it will not reallocate the underlying buffer .

Answer (score -1):

Each time you update your array, it needs to call glBindBuffer relative BufferObject handler to active this Array Buffer or Element Buffer. In addition, if your new array is larger than the old Buffer, calling glBufferData is needed, otherwise, it only needs to call glBufferSubData.